# How to avoid using random_id for Managed Instance Group creation in GCP

Tags: terraform, gcloud

Please help me to understand if I may avoid **"random_id"** using for **Managed Instance group** creation in **GCP**. 
I know it is possible for the **Unmanaged instance group** where I can specify the exact names for instances. 
But for MIG I always have some suffix with random_id

Answer (score 2):

I think you can't and it's because the service needs a way to name instances that it creates. The service will use the template to create instances on-the-fly in order to maintain the number of instances that you define. Each instance requires a unique name.

A simple numbering system (could result in gaps and) would require the current number to be persisted.

Random suffixes are used because it's very improbable (but possibly, possible) for a random name to collide.

Conceptually (!) you should treat the instances as cattle not pets ([link](http://cloudscaling.com/blog/cloud-computing/the-history-of-pets-vs-cattle/)) too. You(r code) should not prefer a specific instance but should treat all the instances homogeneously.

Corollary: if you want to be able to refer to a specific instance, you probably shouldn't use a managed instance group.

With an unmanaged group you must either manually or via code maintain a list of named instances and so you can define the naming mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

[Stateful Managed Instance Groups](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/stateful-migs) support assigning names to each instance.

`gcloud compute instance-groups managed create-instance instance-group-name \
    --instance managed-instance-name \
    [--region region | --zone zone]`

You can find [more examples here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/working-with-managed-instances#adding_instances_with_specific_names).